# Attaching files to comments with Symfony

Tags: php, file, symfony, comments

How can I add attach files to comments in Symfony ? 
So far I was using FOSCommentBundle but I doubt I can easly add the attach files feature.

Is there a bundle which does that or do I have to code it from scratch by myself ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could override FOSCommentBundle to make it handle files.

There are a lot of bundle to help managing media [SonataMediaBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle) is one of them.

Otherwise you can check on [packagist](https://packagist.org/) for some bundle which already handle this.